# Create groups of people in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I'm doing a web app with angularjs and in this app I need to insert the possibility to create more group of people (the informations about the people are saved in a DB). It's important to save in local the name and the id of every groups and in every of them I need to store the list of the people.
In this app I have 'service' and an app.js for all controllers. Every page of app have its controller.
It's important to know that I have develop a little of this part for storing the variuos group: I've the list of the people and I can search them, I've the textbox for entering the name of the group and I've the checkbox for getting the people's information.
How can I do it?

This is my code in a controller to save the information about the people but every time that I refresh the web the localstorage is overwrite:

```
$scope.selection=[];
        // toggle selection for a given employee by name
        $scope.Selection = function (id) {

            $scope.selection.push(id,$scope.GroupName);             
            window.localStorage['$scope.selection'] = JSON.stringify($scope.selection);
            $scope.selection = JSON.parse(window.localStorage['$scope.selection'] || '{}');
            //alert(angular.toJson(athlete));
        };
```

IN the html code I've:

```
<center><a href="../mobile/#/grouplist"><input type="submit" value="Salva" ng-hide="see" ng-click="savename({{GroupName}},{{Groupid})"/></a></center>`
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Unfortunately, we aren't a discussion forum. Therefore your question is off-topic as "too broad", or not specific enough. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic for more.

Comment: What DB you have, what have you tried, what is your backend language.
Any code samples. We can't help you if we don't know the details.